# A formal proof that $ (P \Rightarrow Q) $ is equivalent to its contrapositive $ (\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P) $.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-explanation, proof-theory

I know how to show this via truth tables, but I’m confused over the formal proof.

Wikipedia tells me that:

> $
>          (P \Rightarrow Q)
>   \equiv (\neg P \lor Q)
>   \equiv (Q \lor \neg P)
>   \equiv (\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P)
>   $.

I don’t understand how we get from $ (P \Rightarrow Q) $ to $ (\neg P \lor Q) $. I also don’t understand how $ (Q \lor \neg P) $ implies $ (\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P) $.

Comment: "if it rains then the ground gets wet" ($P\implies Q$). Now can it happen that both following statemens are not true: 1)"it is not raining" and  2)"the ground is getting wet."? No it cannot, so at least one of them is true ($\neg P\vee Q$)

Comment: Before seeking a formal proof, you need to specify which proof calculus you wish to use. There are three well-known ones: Hilbert Calculus, Natural Deduction and Sequent Calculus.

Comment: Another way to convince yourself is to make truth tables for the two statements. There are two variables, $P$ and $Q$, so there are four possibilities for the truth values (both false, $P$ false and $Q$ true, $P$ true and $Q$ false, and both false). For each of the four possibilites, find the truth value of $P\implies Q$ and the truth value of $\neg Q\implies P$. You’ll find that in each of the four cases the truth value of  $P\implies Q$ is the same as the truth value of $\neg Q\implies P$. Thus the two are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
       (P \Rightarrow Q)
\equiv (\neg P \lor Q)
\equiv (Q \lor \neg P)
\equiv (\neg \neg Q \lor \neg P)
\equiv (\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P)
$.

Comment: Thank you! But could you tell me the logic behind P⇒Q = ¬PvQ  and ¬(¬Q)v(¬P) = ¬Q⇒¬P?

Comment: Its just manipulation.Which part you did not understand?

Comment: DrHab replied above so I now I understand P⇒Q = ¬PvQ . I'm confused over how ¬(¬Q)v(¬P) = ¬Q⇒¬P. I guess I should provide context by saying this is my first very rigorous proof-based class.

Comment: Let X=¬Q and Y=¬P then ¬(¬Q)v(¬P) =¬XvY = X⇒Y.Does this solve the problem?

Comment: OH, now I get it. Thank you so much!